# How to group collection by some criteria in Julia?

Tags: julia

Given the list

```
list = [("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 3)]
```

How could it be grouped into something like code below? **Is there a bulit-in function** (slightly different form is ok)?

```
[
  [("a", 1), ("a", 2)]
  [("b", 3)]
]
```

Possibly with something like

```
group((symbol, value) -> symbol, list)
```

Comment: If the list is large, creating a Dict{String,Vector{Int}} might be more efficient than transforming one list into another.

Comment: I don't think there is, but it could certainly be useful. There's a `split` function on `AbstractString` that could possibly be extended for `AbstractVector`. Though I agree with Bill that a Dict might be more ideomatic here.

Comment: Thanks, eventually I just wrote it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataFrames.jl`:

```
julia> using DataFrames                                                                           

julia> list = [(rand('a':'e'), rand(0:9)) for j in 1:8 ]
8-element Array{Tuple{Char,Int64},1}:                                                           
('b', 4)                                                                                       
('b', 4)                                                                                       
('d', 4)                                                                                       
('e', 8)                                                                                       
('b', 2)                                                                                       
('c', 4)                                                                                       
('c', 3)                                                                                       
('b', 5)   

julia> df = DataFrame(letter = first.(list), number = map(t -> t[2], list));                                                                                                                  

julia> gp = groupby(df, :letter);                                                                                                                                                             

julia> [[(r.letter, r.number) for r in eachrow(gdf)] for gdf in gp]                            
4-element Array{Array{Tuple{Char,Int64},1},1}:                                                  
[('b', 4), ('b', 4), ('b', 2), ('b', 5)]                                                       
[('d', 4)]                                                                                     
[('e', 8)]                                                                                     
[('c', 4), ('c', 3)]
```

If your data are large, you may want `JuliaDB.jl`

Answer (score 0):

The standard lib doesn't have such function, eventually I wrote it myself

```
groupby(f, list::Array) = begin
  foldl(list; init = Dict()) do dict, v
    push!(get!(dict, f(v), []), v)
    dict
  end
end
```

Would be nice to have it in standard lib